# mixed model with fixed y for each ID

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I have an experiment in which mice roam a maze with different environments. My predictors are environment (`env`) A, B and C, and exploration time at each environment (`time`).

My dependent variable `y` refers to activity score (the amount of times a mouse pressed a lever in an unrelated task), which means that each mouse has the same value of `y` across `env`:

```
head(dat)

mouse  y  env  time  
1     12  A    22.30
1     12  B    18.51
1     12  C    2.24
2     21  A    14.89
2     21  B    13.98
2     21  C    19.21
3     8   A    10.21
3     8   B    5.12
3     8   C    4.12
```

I'd like to test if the amount of time in each `env` can explain the activity score of mice. I thought of a mixed model like this:

```
lmer(y ~ env*time + (1|mouse), data=dat)
```

but I'm not sure if this is valid since `y` does not vary along `env`. Do lmer models require y to vary across different levels of the predictor variables?

Comment: I'm confused. Your mice don't vary at all between three environments? Clearly *between mice* there is variation, but it seems odd they would have the exact same *within mice* variation in three different scenarios.

Comment: @Shawn, that's really the question. The `y` variable refers to each mouse's activity in a previous task (without environments). So `y` will be the same for the three environments in the current task. Normally, `y` would be added as a covariate I guess, but my question is whether it's statistically valid to add it as the dependent variable